# How to change default recovery for new databases?

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, sql-server-2012

How can i configure the database server on our development server so that when new databases are created that they are `Simple` recovery model by default?

Currently if we remember, when creating a database we have to click on the options tab and select Simple.

In a previous version of SQL i remember that I could set Simple as the default for new databases. How can this be set for Sql Server 2012?

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Change the recovery mode of the database named "model".

From [this MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175987(sql.90).aspx#Anchor_4):

> A new database inherits its recovery model from the **model** database. The default recovery model of the **model** database depends on the edition of SQL Server. But this can be changed by anyone that has ALTER permission on the database.

Answer (score 7):

Change the recovery model of the `model` system database.

Answer (score 4):

In previous versions you would set that on the model database, which is the "model" for new databases. I'm assuming it's the same in SQL Server 2012.